# Sliding images left and right of gallery

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, image-gallery

This is code for the [**jSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kem656qL/5/).
Here i am trying to make sure that the **red** i.e the `.selected` div is **always in the view of the user** wherever i slide my images next or previous.

I **DONT** want to use **Plugins** for this!

**HTML**

```
<div class="base-c">
    <div class="base">
        <div class="images" set="5">5</div>
        <div class="images selected" set="6">6</div>
        <div class="images" set="7">7</div>
        <div class="images" set="8">8</div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="prv">Prev</button>
<button id="nxt">Next</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.base-c {
    width:80%;
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
}
.base {
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left:0px;
    width:100%;
}
.images {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    padding:5px;
    border:2px solid #000;
    display:inline-block;
}
.images.selected {
    background:red;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var spb = $('.base');
var limit = 20; //20 images in max
var from, to;
$(document).on('click', '#prv', function () {
    var set = parseInt($('.images.selected').attr('set'));
    if (set > 0) {
        $('.images.selected').removeClass('selected');

        var ci = $('.images[set="' + (set - 1) + '"]');

        if (ci.length == 0) {
            to = set - 1;
            from = to - 3;
            if (from < 0) {
                from = limit;
            }
            var str = "";
            for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) {
                str += '<div class="images" set="' + i + '">' + i + '</div>';
            }

            spb.prepend(str);
            ci = $('.images[set="' + (set - 1) + '"]');
        }
        ci.addClass('selected');
        spbgoLilright(100);
    }
});
$(document).on('click', '#nxt', function () {
    var set = parseInt($('.images.selected').attr('set'));
    if (set < limit) {
        $('.images.selected').removeClass('selected');
        var ci = $('.images[set="' + (set + 1) + '"]');

        if (ci.length == 0) {
            from = set + 1;
            to = from + 3;
            if (to > limit) {
                to = limit;
            }
            for (var i = from; i < to; i++) {
                spb.append('<div class="images" set="' + i + '">' + i + '</div>');
            }
            ci = $('.images[set="' + (set + 1) + '"]');
        }
        ci.addClass('selected');

        spbgoLilleft(100);
    }
});

function spbgoLilleft(step) {
    var mL = parseInt(spb.css('marginLeft'));
    mL = mL - step;
    spb.css('marginLeft', mL);
}

function spbgoLilright(step) {
    var mL = parseInt(spb.css('marginLeft'));
    mL = mL + step;
    if (mL < 0) {
        mL = 0;
    }
    spb.css('marginLeft', mL);
}
```

Comment: My only question is... Why? Why invent the wheel again? That is the charm with web development. If you REALLY want to do this on your own,look up other solutions and learn from them. I dislike javascript too much to give it a go :)

Comment: ok then any solutions @thommyjonasson ?

Comment: IF you google: Jquery Slideshow you get a insane amount of hits and variations of designs. http://www.slidesjs.com/ <-- This one looked pretty neat and easy to implement. http://www.jssor.com/ <-- Another long list. Trust me on this, but going backwards by taking someone elses example and change it is easier than creating your own. Not always the case in all programming, but definitely here.